# Response for preflight is invalid angular 5

Tags: angular

I want to make an HTTP request to a server and I used the HTTP library in angular 5 like this:

```
return this.http.post('http://localhost/api-panel/index.php/admin-api-user/check-session', []);
```

This is my subscription to HTTP observable:

```
.subscribe((response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
    },
      (error) => {
      console.log('error', error);
      });
```

But I got the following error in console:

`Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)`

When I use this code, The result is ok:

```
$.post('http://localhost/api-panel/index.php/admin-api-user/check-session', (res, err) => {
      console.log('result of $.get', res);
      console.log('result of ...', err);
    });
```

and the problem is when I want to use the HTTP.

NOTE: I have put an empty array in http.post parameters because this method didn't take any argument

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, The problem was the parameter, I should Be an empty string, not `{}` or `[]`.